# getViewer().setSelection() not working with FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

I would like to set focus to a specifc row in a `TableViewer`.

The focus and input handing is defined like this:

```
ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(viewer, ToolTip.NO_RECREATE);

FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter fch = new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(viewer);
TableViewerFocusCellManager focusCellManager = new TableViewerFocusCellManager(viewer, fch);

ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy actSupport = new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(viewer) {
            protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(final 
                   ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {
                return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL
                        || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_CLICK_SELECTION
                        || (event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.KEY_PRESSED && event.keyCode == SWT.F2)
                        || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC;
            }
};

TableViewerEditor.create(viewer, actSupport, ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_HORIZONTAL
                | ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_MOVE_TO_ROW_NEIGHBOR |
                 ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_VERTICAL
                | ColumnViewerEditor.KEYBOARD_ACTIVATION);
```

The code to select a row is:

```
getViewer().setSelection(new StructuredSelection(parameterTable.getViewer().getElementAt(selection)), false);
```

The problem is, that as soon as I use the `FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter`, `setSelection` no longer works, meaning that no row is selected.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Regards
  Roger

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution. Just elaborating what could be an issue. 
I see a problem in

```
FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter:110 line


                    ViewerCell cell = row.getCell(event.index);

                    if (focusCell == null || !cell.equals(focusCell)) {
                        removeSelectionInformation(event, cell);
                    } else {
                        markFocusedCell(event, cell);
                    }
```

initial focus cell will be default top index of `Table`.  focus cell and selection cell will not be equal so it is removing selection background on the selected cell.